# UIButton Subclass memory leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uibutton

I have a sub class of a `UIButton` and I have added a `NSString` property.

Do I need to release/=nil this property at some point? Or wil this automatically happen when the button itself is set to nil?

If so where would I do it?

Comment: Are you using ARC? What do you mean "button itself is set to nil"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ARC, you don't have to do anything; ARC will automatically add some destructor code that will release the instance variable for you.

If you're not using ARC, you should convert to ARC. But failing that, if your property is `retain`/`strong` or `copy`, you should add a line to `dealloc` that releases your instance variable without using the accessor. You don't have to nil it out because your object is about to be destroyed anyway, but you can if you want to.